# Limit hashid to 2 character hash

Tags: javascript, hash, hashids

I am using the hashids library to generate a unique hash using 2 inputs. I know there is a way to add padding to extend the length of the hash. Is there a way to truncate or set a max length to the hashid constructor?

Comment: Couldnt you get the full hash and then simply run something like `hashString.slice(0,2);`?

Comment: @SMT Yes, but then you can't guarantee that the hash will be unique. For example if there are 2 hashes generated, ABCD and ABDC respectively, then if you took the first 2 characters from them, it would appear they are the same. I need to ensure they are unique.

Comment: if you only want two characters produced wouldn't you face this issue anyways?

Comment: @SMT to clarify I meant length of 2 characters, not just a combination of 2 specific characters.

Comment: So if I can clarify, my misunderstanding was that I assumed you just wanted the first two characters. You in fact want ANY two characters from the hashid generated, correct? Regardless of how you're choosing the 2 characters from a string of N length, it still seems like you'll run into the issue of non-uniqueness eventually. Happy to help you try and figure this out if I'm still not misunderstanding what you're going for.